# Error running identical function when comparing two vectors

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a vector (length 8) and change one element randomly in the vector each time the for loop run. I want to check my new generated vector with a fixed vector (Destination) and save the valid case in a counting variable (Time_to_Destination). However, when I use identical() function, there was no saved recorded in Time_to_Destination. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I tried identical(), all.equal()
If I commented out if(identical()), the variable Time_to_Destination was counted

```
rm(list = ls())

library(igraph)
#Plot the graph
graph_MC <- graph(edge = c(1,2,1,3,2,3,2,4,3,4), n = 4, directed = F)

plot(graph_MC)
#Initial position
X_0 <- c(1,2,3,1)

Destination <- c(3,1,2,3)

X <- X_0

Time_to_destination <- 0
#I would like to see how many time I arrive to the Destination, which have a valid set of color
for(i in 1:10000){
  #Generate a random node
  a <- as.integer(runif(1,1,4))
  #Generate a random color of the node
  q <- as.integer(runif(1,1,3))

  test_vector <- X

  test_vector[a] = q
  #Check if the new set of color is valid
  if (a == 1) {
    if ((q != test_vector[2]) & (q != test_vector[3])) {
      X = test_vector 
      if (identical(X, Destination)){
        Time_to_destination = Time_to_destination + 1
      }
    }
  }

  if (a == 2) {
    if ((q != test_vector[1]) & (q != test_vector[3]) & (q != test_vector[4])) {
      X = test_vector
      if (identical(X, Destination)){
        Time_to_destination = Time_to_destination + 1
      }
    }
  }


  if (a == 3) {
    if ((q != test_vector[1]) & (q != test_vector[2]) & (q != test_vector[4])) {
      X = test_vector 
      if (identical(X, Destination)){
        Time_to_destination = Time_to_destination + 1
      }
    }
  }


  if (a == 4) {
    if ((q != test_vector[3]) & (q != test_vector[2])) {
      X = test_vector 
      if (identical(X, Destination)){
        Time_to_destination = Time_to_destination + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
Time_to_destination
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. It would really help if you were to reduce your issue to a minimal problem. Provide *minimal*, representative sample data (use a fixed random seed for random data) and a *minimal* code example that illustrates what you're trying to do (include expected output) and what didn't work. I can guarantee that you'll attract a lot more attention.

Comment: Dear Mr. Evers,
Thank you for your comment. I've made a smaller example and added more details into my code. I hope I can get some help from your expertise. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. There is still a lot of unnecessary code (for example, `plot`ting the `igraph` does not seem relevant). In your first sentence you mention "*a vector (length 8)*" but I don't see any vector of that length in your code. It is also not clear to me what you're trying to test in the `for` loop. A proper problem description would help understanding what it is you're trying to do. Providing your expected output would also help in that context. Lastly, always use a fixed random seed to ensure reproducibility when working with random numbers.